# Solr join for multiple collection with each collection have multiple shards

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud

I have *two collections*:

- `CollectionOne` with two shards `(shard1, shard2)` have `id`, `name`, and `Address` fields
- `CollectionTwo` with shards `(shard1,shard2)` have `c_id`, `code`, and `State` fields.

I want the result from two collection on `id=c_id` base using `join`.

Please provide me full help! I am using `Solr` version 6.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch - Distributed Search doesn't support join.
So SolrCloud can do join only when index is not splited to shards.

Comment: Now with SOLR version 8.6.0, it is possible to join between multiple shared and multiple collection. I tried to achieve the same but getting error. Please refer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76578595/apache-solr-from-version-8-6-0-joining-between-multiple-collections-and-multip