# Apache SOLR from Version 8.6.0 - Joining between Multiple Collections and Multiple Shards in each collection

Tags: solr, sharding, solrcloud, cross-correlation, solrconfig

Please consider SOLR version greater than 8.6.0 for this query. There are many questions regarding this issue but all are before version 8.6.0 and at that time SOLR was not supporting Join between multiple shards and multiple collection.

Now refer below links, it mention that SOLR supports Join between multiple collection and multiple shards. Refer Solr 8.6.0 Release Highlights: in this news.
https://solr.apache.org/news.html

Also, SOLR provides guidance how to configure and achieve the same. Refer Join Query Parser Definition in solrconfig.xml in below link
https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/other-parsers.html

I have also gone through below link for configuration
https://kmwllc.com/index.php/2020/07/15/the-cross-collection-join-query/

Please review below configuration for local and other collection, schema structure and join query

**Local Collection Name - loc_1 collection**

**Other Collection Name - oth_1 collection**

**loc_id (loc_1 collection) is a join key with oth_id (other collection)**

1. loc_1 Collection (local collection) -

schema.xml

```
<field name="loc_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name="loc_auth" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

solrconfig.xml file

```
<queryParser name="join" class="org.apache.solr.search.JoinQParserPlugin">
    <str name="routerField">loc_id</str>
    </queryParser>
```

2. oth_1 Collection (remote collection) -

schema.xml

```
<field name="oth_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="oth_auth" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

solrconfig.xml file

```
<cache name="hash_oth_id"  
       class="solr.CaffeineCache"
       size="128"
       initialSize="0"
       regenerator="solr.NoOpRegenerator"/>
```

I can successfully execute below query in Local environment with single Shard only and retrieve data from both collection.
I am passing in local collection with fq.

```
loc_auth:123 OR {!join from=oth_id to=loc_id fromIndex=oth_1}oth_auth:123
```

But, above query fails with Multiple Shard on QA environment so, with help of above links, I have modify solrconfig.xml file as per above. Then execute the same query by just adding method=crossCollection. Please refer below join query for cross collection which I am passing in fq.

```
loc_auth:123 OR {!join method=crossCollection from=oth_id to=loc_id fromIndex=oth_1}oth_auth:123
```

It throws error as given here. Please any one can help if I am missing some configuration or need any changes in Shared configuration or need to re-create the shared structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <bool name="zkConnected">true</bool>
  <int name="status">500</int>
  <int name="QTime">8</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
  <lst name="metadata">
    <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
    <str name="root-error-class">java.lang.RuntimeException</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="msg">java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: params method=crossCollection&amp;q=oth_auth:123&amp;fl=oth_id&amp;sort=oth_id+asc&amp;qt=/export&amp;wt=javabin&amp;distrib=false</str>
  <str name="trace">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: params method=crossCollection&amp;q=oth_auth:123&amp;fl=oth_id&amp;sort=oth_id+asc&amp;qt=/export&amp;wt=javabin&amp;distrib=false
    at org.apache.solr.search.join.CrossCollectionJoinQuery$CrossCollectionJoinQueryWeight.getDocSet(CrossCollectionJoinQuery.java:300)
    at org.apache.solr.search.join.CrossCollectionJoinQuery$CrossCollectionJoinQueryWeight.scorer(CrossCollectionJoinQuery.java:311)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Weight.scorerSupplier(Weight.java:148)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanWeight.scorerSupplier(BooleanWeight.java:379)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanWeight.scorer(BooleanWeight.java:344)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher$FilterImpl$FilterSet.iterator(SolrIndexSearcher.java:2366)
    at org.apache.solr.search.Filter$1.scorer(Filter.java:133)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.Weight.bulkScorer(Weight.java:182)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ConstantScoreQuery$1.bulkScorer(ConstantScoreQuery.java:121)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:656)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:443)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.buildAndRunCollectorChain(SolrIndexSearcher.java:211)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1595)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1412)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:596)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.doProcessUngroupedSearch(QueryComponent.java:1500)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:390)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:369)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:216)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2637)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:794)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:567)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: params method=crossCollection&amp;q=oth_auth:123&amp;fl=oth_id&amp;sort=oth_id+asc&amp;qt=/export&amp;wt=javabin&amp;distrib=false
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream.openStreams(CloudSolrStream.java:398)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream.open(CloudSolrStream.java:274)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.PushBackStream.open(PushBackStream.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.ReducerStream.open(ReducerStream.java:200)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.UniqueStream.open(UniqueStream.java:151)
    at org.apache.solr.search.join.CrossCollectionJoinQuery$CrossCollectionJoinQueryWeight.getDocSet(CrossCollectionJoinQuery.java:286)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: params method=crossCollection&amp;q=oth_auth:123&amp;fl=oth_id&amp;sort=oth_id+asc&amp;qt=/export&amp;wt=javabin&amp;distrib=false
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream.openStreams(CloudSolrStream.java:392)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: params method=crossCollection&amp;q=oth_auth:123&amp;fl=oth_id&amp;sort=oth_id+asc&amp;qt=/export&amp;wt=javabin&amp;distrib=false
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.SolrStream.open(SolrStream.java:132)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream$StreamOpener.call(CloudSolrStream.java:504)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.CloudSolrStream$StreamOpener.call(CloudSolrStream.java:493)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version (expected 2, but 123) or the data in not in 'javabin' format
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec._init(JavaBinCodec.java:213)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.initRead(JavaBinCodec.java:202)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.JavabinTupleStreamParser.&lt;init&gt;(JavabinTupleStreamParser.java:44)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.SolrStream.constructParser(SolrStream.java:314)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.SolrStream.open(SolrStream.java:130)
    ... 7 more
</str>
  <int name="code">500</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: A 500 error is a server side error, so the first thing would be to upgrade to the most recent version of Solr to avoid any already fixed bugs and security issues (log4j2, for example); look at the log for each node as well. A 500 error isn't generally because of the query, but is an unexpected server side issue. And please do not spam the comment section of other answers; people will see your question when they look at the Solr page and have something to say.

Comment: @MatsLindh we already have SOLR version 8.9.0 with multiple shards in each collection. Will check logs and get back again. And deleted that comment, sorry my intension is just to resolve this issue. Thanks for guidance of taking care while adding comments

Comment: Make sure you've replaced the bundled log4j2 jars if you're using a Solr version prior to 8.11.1 (or make sure you're using a docker image where the issue has been mitigated).

Comment: @MatsLindh With below error, I try to replicate manually on sharedobjectdetail collection (remote collection) and found that when I provide wt=javabin, it throws the error. How it append this value with query?

[c:folders s:shard1 r:core_node2 x:folders_shard1_replica_n1] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: params method=crossCollection&q=shared_with_object_ids:1935927&fl=object_id&sort=object_id+asc&qt=/export&wt=javabin&distrib=false

Comment: I trace and got info like : The "wt=javabin" is correct since that's that SolrJ uses. It also makes sense that this won't work from your browser since it's binary format.
Then the left is same error which I mention in description (org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)